# Is it possible to put a switch statement inside of a Conditional (ternary)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm really new to using Conditional (ternary) operator. Is it possible to put a switch statement in this operator?

This is what i tried:

```
function find(cn, romanNum) {
        if (cn >= 1 && cn <= 3) {
          return repeatString(romanNum[2], cn);
       }
        cn > 5 && cn < 9 ? return romanNum[1] + repeatString(romanNum[2], cn - 5) : switch(cn) {
            case 4:
            return romanNum[2] + romanNum[1];
            case 5: 
            return romanNum[1];
            case 9:
            return romanNum[2] + romanNum[0];
    }
}
```

I'm doing something wrong i know, but what is it? Everyone is new to something at some point in time.

---

**Error:**

- Expected a identifier and instead saw `'return'`.
- Expected `':'` and instead saw `'romanNum'`.
- Missing semicolon.
- Expected `'}'` to match `'{'` from line 58 and instead saw `':'`

This is the right es5 code:

```
function find(cn, romanNum) {
        if (cn >= 1 && cn <= 3) {
            return repeatString(romanNum[2], cn);
        } else if (cn == 4) {
            return romanNum[2] + romanNum[1];
        } else if (cn == 5) {
            return romanNum[1];
        } else if (cn == 9) {
            return romanNum[2] + romanNum[0];
        }
        if (cn > 5 && cn < 9) {
            return romanNum[1] + repeatString(romanNum[2], cn - 5);
        }
    }
```

Help?

Comment: No, that is not possible. Since `?:` is an operator, its operands have to be expressions, but `switch` is a statement – not an expression. (Same with `return`.) You might have been hoping for https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pattern-matching?

Comment: Don't force use of a ternary here. Ternarys are exclusively meant to evaluate to one of two values. Your use here is abuse. Just us an if.

Comment: Why would you want to write such cryptic code anyway?

Comment: *"Is it possible"* - well you tried it and got numerous syntax errors, so can you guess?

Comment: I just wanted to make my code smaller/ simplified. I could be close, i could be very off. That is why i am asking you guys.

Comment: smaller ≠ simplified

Comment: @Leed Don't sacrifice readability to make code smaller. Just use an if.

Comment: IMO It's a good question hence my +1. It's just that your end goal argument is flawed. You'll make this harder to understand for anyone visiting your codebase later. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: In my opinion its just as easy to read. Not many people will see this code besides you guys. Here is the the place where the code is from --> https://repl.it/@John_Nicole/Intermediate-Algorithm-Scripting-Roman-Numeral-Converter

Comment: [Your code should read like a story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose)

Comment: Don't they have multi-level? Like evaluating 3 or more? I already got this to work with a if statement, just trying it another way.

Comment: Simpler is always better, even if it is a little longer. Even if you're the only one reading the code a few days/months/years later you might have a hard time reading it. Although I agree with  Nicholas, it is a good question.

Comment: Should i just abandon this idea and go with the es5 code i listed above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested ternary whith an object as replacement for the `select` structure.

```
function find(cn, romanNum) {
    return cn >= 1 && cn <= 3
        ? repeatString(romanNum[2], cn)
        : cn > 5 && cn < 9
            ? romanNum[1] + repeatString(romanNum[2], cn - 5)
            : {
                4: romanNum[2] + romanNum[1],
                5: romanNum[1],
                9: romanNum[2] + romanNum[0]
            }[cn];
}
```

A step further, you could omit the second ternary and use the first condition as default value for the result of non existent property of the object.

```
function find(cn, romanNum) {
    return cn >= 1 && cn <= 3
        ? repeatString(romanNum[2], cn)
        : {
            4: romanNum[2] + romanNum[1],
            5: romanNum[1],
            9: romanNum[2] + romanNum[0]
        }[cn] || romanNum[1] + repeatString(romanNum[2], cn - 5);
}
```

Comment: Your is the shortest, thanks. Its also pretty understandable. Thanks. Also thanks to everyone else who answered too :)

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr: kind of, but you shouldn't do it** since it is not that readable.
Always keep code short an simple but verbose.

**Long answer:**
You could wrap your switch inside an immediately invoked anonymous function.

```js
const a = 20;
const condition = a > 100;
const result = condition ? true : ( () => {
  switch ( a ) {
    case 11: return 22;
    case 20: return 21;
    default: return 100;
  }
} )();

console.log( result );
```

But not only is this more complex but also harder to read.

It is better to use a verbose coding style.
In your case something like this would be cleaner and more readable:

```js
function test( a ) {
  const condition = a > 100;

  if ( condition ) {
    return true;
  }
  
  switch ( a ) {
    case 20: return 21;
    default: return 100;
  }
}

console.log( test( 20 ) );
```

Comment: How would i do true and false? I want it do run a line of code if true, or switch if not true.

Comment: I updated my answer with a more readable code example at the end

Answer (score 4):

You can use an IIFE:

```
return condition
  ? (() => {
      switch (val) {
        case x: return a;
        case y: return b;
        default: return c;
      }
    })()
  : other;
```

however this is horribly unreadable and not even shorter than the simple `if` statement.

---

That said, there is a much better choice than `switch` for looking up values: a lookup table! Just use an object, array or `Map` and use your `cn` as the property name.

```
const table = {
  1: repeatString(romanNum[2], 1),
  2: repeatString(romanNum[2], 2),
  3: repeatString(romanNum[2], 3),
  4: romanNum[2] + romanNum[1],
  5: romanNum[1],
  6: romanNum[1] + repeatString(romanNum[2], 1),
  7: romanNum[1] + repeatString(romanNum[2], 2),
  8: romanNum[1] + repeatString(romanNum[2], 3),
  9: romanNum[2] + romanNum[0]
};
function find(cn) {
  return table[cn];
}

// using an array similar to the object above:
table = [
  ...Array.from({length: 4}, (_, i) => repeatString(romanNum[2], i))
  romanNum[2] + romanNum[1],
  ...Array.from({length: 4}, (_, i) => romanNum[1] +  repeatString(romanNum[2], i)),
  romanNum[2] + romanNum[0]
];
```

Comment: So it will go through the table and return based on cn's value?

Comment: It won't go *through* the table. It will go to the right spot in the table directly.

Comment: i tried it, and it isn't returning the right thing --> https://repl.it/@John_Nicole/Intermediate-Algorithm-Scripting-Roman-Numeral-Converter (line 58, i put some old es5 code their for now).

Answer (score 1):

1. U cant use the return like this just a small example to show how to return in normal ternary operator

   ```
   function find(cn, romanNum) {
       if (cn >= 1 && cn <= 3) {
        return 2;
      }

     return  (cn > 5 && cn < 9) ? ( romanNum[1] + 2, cn - 5) : 3
   ```

   }
2. No its not possible to use switch statement in ternary operator because switch is a statement not a condition or  expression
3. Better use if -else
4. If you want to stick to ternary then make the changes like

```js
function find(cn, romanNum) {
        if (cn >= 1 && cn <= 3) {
          return repeatString(romanNum[2], cn);
       }
      return  cn > 5 && cn < 9 ?  romanNum[1] + repeatString(romanNum[2], cn - 5) : (cn===4 ?   romanNum[2] + romanNum[1]:
          (cn==5 ? romanNum[1] : romanNum[2] + romanNum[0]))
}

console.log(find(2,[1,2,3,4]))
```

Though I wont prefer nested ternary operator as it hinders the readability of the code .